# Export functions in Xcode Framework dylib

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, dylib

I wanted to export some functions in a framework and performed a comparison between a dylib created from Xcode Framework and a dylib created using clang and I used similar code in both files.

```
#define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))

//! Project version number for importdylib2.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double importdylib2VersionNumber;

//! Project version string for importdylib2.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char importdylib2VersionString[];

void importdylib();
void exitimport();

//Initializer
__attribute__((constructor))
static void initializer(void)
{
    importdylib();
}
 
//Finalizer
__attribute__((destructor))
static void finalizer(void)
{
    exitimport();
}

EXPORT
void importdylib()
{
  //some code
}

EXPORT
void exitimport()
{
    //some code
}
```

However, when I load the binaries in Ghidra, I saw that the dylib created by Xcode archive process did not contain any of my exported functions but the dylib created from clang contain the expected functions.

**Xcode Framework dylib**

The Exports did not contain my exported functions and the list of Functions is empty.

Exports

- _importdylib2VersionNumber
- _importdylib2VersionString

**Dylib compiled from clang**

I can see the various functions, including exported functions.

Exports

- _exitimport
- _importdylib

Functions

- ___GLOBAL_init_65535
- _exitimport
- _finalizer
- _importdylib
- _initializer

What settings do I need to configure in Xcode to export functions in a framework?